# Get JS date format string

Tags: angular, date, ngx-translate, messageformat.js

For our Angular 4 application I'm using ngx-translate with messageformat.js for handling internationalization and localization. Is it possible to get the format string of shortdate of a date object ie. 'YYYY-MM-dd'?

ie: `new Date().formatString('en-US')` returns: `'YYYY-MM-dd'`

Answer (score -1):

```
const pipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe(locale) //en-Ukr
return pipe.transform(value, 'y-MM-DD') // value = new Date()
'2017-12-04'
```

Comment: Actually I would like to have the string 'YYYY-mm-dd' so I can show it as a place holder text in a date input.

Comment: pipe.transform - will returns you a string

Comment: It returns the actual date as a string but I'm looking the exact sting: 'YYYY-mm-dd'. The date formater as a string.